# How can I see old versions of a question or answer?

Tags: support, revision-history

My question was just edited. It seems I had used wildly differing tags. Happy that someone helped me, it also made me a little bit curious what I had done. So, how can I see the older versions of my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the left of the poster's name will be the name of the last editor. Above this, a link saying when the post was last edited. Click it and you'll get a detailed revision history with diffs from edit to edit. Each revision will have a chain icon labelled "link to this formatted revision" that will show the post as it was after a given editor's changes.

[image: Screenshot of diff link]

[image: Screenshot of formatted source link]

Took me a while to stumble across too...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. :)